# Electron PDF viewer

Tags: node.js, pdf, electron

I have an Electron app that loads URL from PHP server. And the page contains an iFrame having a source to PDF. The PDF page seems absolutely ok in a normal web browser but asks for download in Electron. Any help?

My codes for html page is

```
<h1>Hello World!</h1>
Some html content here...
<iframe src="http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/compressed.tracemonkey-pldi-09.pdf" width="1200" height="800"></iframe>
```

And my js code is something like

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600})
mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'),
protocol: 'file:',
slashes: true
}))

app.on('ready', createWindow)
```

Any help would be really greatful...

Comment: See this question if you are using Electron 3.0.0 or later: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52844135/7910454

Answer (score 23):

Electron is shipping already with an integrated PDF viewer.

So you can load PDF files just like normal HTML files, the PDF viewer will automatically show up.

E.g. in `BrowserWindow` with `.loadURL(…)`, in `<iframes>`, `<object>` and also with the, at the moment discouraged, `<webview>`.

PS: The need to enable the `plugins` property in the `BrowserWindow` or `<webview>` is no more needed since Electron 9.

Comment: Since I updated to the latest electron version and added the snippet above... it finally works with:

`<iframe src="./pdf-test.pdf"></iframe>`

Thanks for sharing this!

Comment: @flori enabled the plugins but it still just downloading the files instead of displaying them..

Comment: @MiXT4PE Hard to guess … maybe start a new question with your code and the HTTP headers of the PDF request?

Comment: @flori Thanks for the answer. I solved it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52844135/view-pdf-in-electron-browserwindow

Answer (score 1):

You will need 
https://github.com/gerhardberger/electron-pdf-window

Example:

```
const { app } = require('electron')
const PDFWindow = require('electron-pdf-window')

app.on('ready', () => {
  const win = new PDFWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600
  })

win.loadURL('http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/compressed.tracemonkey-pldi-09.pdf')
```

})

Comment: Tried that but that is useful only fir direct pdf link, I have an iFrame  which has a url to pdf. that didnt worked...

Comment: 1.6.4 will contain native support for PDF render: See API changes in release notes: https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/tag/v1.6.4

Answer (score 0):

This answer will focus on implementation with Angular.

After year of waiting (to be solved by the [Electron](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/12337)) finally I decided to  apply a workaround. For the people who needs it done, here it goes. Workaround comes with a cost of increasing bundle size totally 500K. (For Angular)

Workaround to use Mozilla PDF.js library.

- [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-pdfjs-viewer)
- [GitHub](https://github.com/intbot/ng2-pdfjs-viewer)

**Implementation 1 (Setting `nodeIntegration: true`)**

This implementation has no issue, you can implement by the document of the library mentioned. But if you run into additional problem like creating white window when route is changed, it is due to the setting `nodeIntegration` property to `true`. If so, use the following implementation.

**Implementation 2 (Setting `nodeIntegration: false`)**

This is the default by Electron. Using this configuration and viewing the PDF is bit tricky. Solution is to use `Uint8Array` instead of a `blob` or `base64`.

You can use the following function to convert `base64` to `Uint8Array`.

```js
base64ToArrayBuffer(data): Uint8Array {
  const input = data.substring(data.indexOf(',') + 1);
  const binaryString = window.atob(input ? input : data);
  const binaryLen = binaryString.length;
  const bytes = new Uint8Array(binaryLen);
  for (let i = 0; i < binaryLen; i++) {
    const ascii = binaryString.charCodeAt(i);
    bytes[i] = ascii;
  }
  return bytes;
}
```

Or convert blob to array buffer

```js
const blob = response;
let arrayBuffer = null;

arrayBuffer = await new Response(blob).arrayBuffer();
```

then pass the generated `Uint8Array` as the `pdfSource` to the `ng2-pdfjs-viewer`.

HTML

```html
<ng2-pdfjs-viewer zoom="100" [pdfSrc]="pdfSource"></ng2-pdfjs-viewer>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Electron 9.0.0](https://www.electronjs.org/blog/electron-9-0) has enabled PDF viewer already.

`npm install electron@9.0.0`