# How to embed a pdf file in electron

Tags: reactjs, electron

I'm using electron 3.0.0, and react. I need to show a pdf inside one of my react components. I've tried:

[Electron PDF viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43220321/electron-pdf-viewer/43220423#43220423)

https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/11065

Unsuccessfully.

I used this 3 tags, none work

```
<object type="text/html" data={artist.getPdf()} width="100%" height="500" plugins="true"/>
<iframe src={artist.getPdf()} width="100%" height="500" />
<webview src={artist.getPdf()} plugins="true" width="100%" height="500"></webview>
```

All of this attempt to download the file, I just wanna show it inside a  element.

In the electron.js file I put:

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
   ...
   webPreferences: {
     plugins: true
   }
})
```

Comment: I've tried a lot of electron releases, but it's not working, even with electron 4.0.0-beta