# Include a pdf in an electron.js window

Tags: electron, jspdf, preview

I have a web app that creates pdf files and shows a preview. Like so

```
...
<body>
    <iframe id="preview" src=""></iframe>
    <script src="jspdf.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var doc = new jsPDF()
        doc.text(5, 5, 'Hello, world!')
        document.getElementById("preview").src = doc.output("datauristring")
    </script>
</body>
...
```

Problem is, it doesn't work e.g. in IE. So I want to make a desktop app using electron.js. According to this post: >[Electron PDF viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43220321/electron-pdf-viewer) there is a pdf viewer in electron, but the iframe (or webview) is always empty.
Is it somehow possible?